# Trouble invoking command with quoted string using Scala's sys.process API

Tags: scala, command, quoting

As can be seen in the following console session, the same command invoked from Scala produces different results than when run in the terminal.

```
~> scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> """emacsclient --eval '(+ 4 5)'""".!

*ERROR*: End of file during parsingres0: Int = 1

scala> :quit
~> emacsclient --eval '(+ 4 5)'
9
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and/or know of a work around?

I thought this may have been a library bug, so opened an issue as well: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Scala's `sys.process` api doesn't support quoting. The following works: `Seq("emacsclient", "--eval", "(+ 4 5)").!`.